# Why are some Windows in ALT-TAB preview are empty white frames?

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

In Windows 7, when <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ing between windows, some windows are previewed and show their contents. Others appear as an empty white frame with a blank title bar.

When rotating through the windows using <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>, the same windows that are blank white with alt-tab are shown as small empty windows with the folder icon in them.

Why are some windows blank white, and what can be done to cause all windows to display their content and title while selecting with alt-tab?

Comment: I think it probably depends on the application on whether it renders in the preview.

Comment: @tim11g: Please can you give some examples of programs that exhibit this behaviour. Also, is this a new problem or something that has been happening for a while? Have you tried restarting the computer to see if it persists? What specific version of Windows 7 are you using (Basic, Home Premium, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This normally occurs for background processes, which don't actually have a window but is being picked up.